# Why isn't getElementById required to get IDs within a form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn JavaScript to be able to compare it with jQuery. I've been searching for an explanation (or something to prove that Im doing things right) to why IDs within form inputs are seen as name attributes (in the way we select them)

```
<form id="myskills">
    <input type="text" id="skillpg">
</form>
```

If I want to get that input by ID I'd do this:

```
document.getElementById('skillpg');
```

By mistake I found that I can also select the same input by doing this

```
document.getElementById('myskills').skillpg
```

In my mind that code gets an input element with the `name="skillpg"` and not an ID name.

As I'm writing this question, it sounds like something that I should just accept it and move on. But is there a reason not to use this way and just stick with `getElementById` or use the name attribute instead of the ID?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works since [`HTMLFormElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) has a special getter for this:

```
interface HTMLFormElement : HTMLElement {  
    ...
  readonly attribute HTMLFormControlsCollection elements;
  readonly attribute long length;
  getter Element (unsigned long index);
  getter (RadioNodeList or Element) (DOMString name);
};
```

The `getter` wil get used whenver you use `form["name"]`. Since `form.name === form["name"]`, everything is fine, since the [algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-nameditem) for the getter says, that you can also use an id instead of a name:

> When a form element is indexed for named property retrieval, the user agent must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Let candidates be a live `RadioNodeList` object containing all the listed elements whose form owner is the form element that have either an **`id` attribute** or a `name` attribute equal to `name`, [...]

Now back to your question:

> As I'm writing this question, it sounds like something that I should just accept it and move on. But is there a reason not to use this way and just stick with getElementById or use the name attribute instead of the ID?

You shouldn't accept, unless you checked whether it's a) standard and b) compatible to your targeted browsers. Since it's standard, you need to check whether your targeted browsers are compatible. Other than that, it's mostly personal preference.

Comment: hmm i just tested this in chrome, but getting *undefined* when trying to access my div (by id or name): document.forms[0].myDiv

Comment: @SonicSoul: Well, `div`doesn't have a form owner, does it?